# How to recieve input from chat again in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(message.author.bot)
    content = message.content
    author = message.author
    print("{}: {}".format(author, content))

    if message.content.startswith(".play"):
        import random
        words = [
            "expert",
            "error",
            "fairies",
            "star",
            "example",
            "pencil",
            "friction",
            "attraction",
            "horse",
            "vegetable",
            "stove",
            "invention"]
        word = random.choice(words)
        guesses = 7
        hint = ""
        i = 0
        try:
            await message.channel.send("Guess the word!")
            while guesses > 0:
                user_input = await client.wait_for('message', timeout=60.0, check=None)
                user_input = message.content
                print(user_input)
                if user_input == word:
                    await message.channel.send("You found the word!")
                elif user_input != word:
                    await message.channel.send("Guessed wrong!")
                    try:
                        hint += word[i]
                    except IndexError:
                        break
                    i += 1
                    await message.channel.send(f"Here is hint {hint}")
                    guesses -= 1
                    await message.channel.send(f"{guesses} left")
                if guesses == 0:
                    break
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await message.channel.send("Time out!")
```

I tried to entegrate my guessing game into discord bot with python but here is how it goes:

**
__0#1885: .play

#8974: Guess the word!

__0#1885: test

#8974: Guessed wrong!

#8974: Here is hint e

#8974: 6 left

__0#1885: expert

#8974: Guessed wrong!

#8974: Here is hint ex

#8974: 5 left

__0#1885: extra

#8974: Guessed wrong!

#8974: Here is hint exa

#8974: 4 left

__0#1885: example

#8974: Guessed wrong!

#8974: Here is hint exam

#8974: 3 left

__0#1885: asd

#8974: Guessed wrong!

#8974: Here is hint examp

#8974: 2 left

**
As you can see the message is stuck at ".play". (I debugged it) The problem is I do not know how to reset the message and recieve another input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question is written really bad. But still if what your'e searching for is how to get user input here how you do it.

```
import asyncio

@bot.command()
async def some_command(ctx):
    def check(message): # ALL FILTERS GO HERE
        return message.author.id == ctx.author.id and message.channel.id == ctx.channel.id
    
    try:
        message = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=60.0)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send('timeout')
        return
    await ctx.send("Text inputted: "+message.content)
```